# Message queue between parent and child causes invalid arguments in msgsnd

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork, message-queue

The process creates n children (n read from stdin) and each of them have to send a message to the parent after every 2 seconds who then sends every message it receives to all children. I am using 2 message queues: one in which all children send msg to parent and another in which the parent sends the message and every child reads. Every child upon successful sending or receiving prints its pid and data received form the msg queue (data is just a random number).
However the program is showing error "msgsnd: invalid arguments."
I have done some debugging to check if any arguments passed are null or invalid  but its not so. Noe I'm kinda stuck and not really sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct msgbuf {
    long    mtype;
    int     num;
} message_buf;

long n;
void sigalrm(int signo){
        alarm(5);
        n=n+2;
        printf("%ld seconds elapsed\n",n);
        }
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int id1,id2;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key1,key2;
    key1 = ftok ("test2.c", 'A');
    key2 = ftok ("test2.c", 'B');
    message_buf sbuf,rbuf;
    size_t buf_length=sizeof(int);

    time_t t;


        pid_t pid;
        int i,j,k,n;
        n=atoi(argv[1]);

        if ((id1 = msgget(key1, msgflg )) < 0) {
                perror("msgget");
            }
        else 
            printf("Queue 1 created\n");  

        if ((id2 = msgget(key2, msgflg )) < 0) {
                perror("msgget");
            }
        else 
             printf("Queue 2 created\n");        

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid==0)  {
        setpgid(getpid(),getppid());
        signal(SIGALRM, sigalrm);
        alarm(2);
        while(1)        {
                srand((unsigned)time(&t));
                sbuf.mtype = i;
                sbuf.num=rand()%50;

                if  (msgsnd(id1, &sbuf, buf_length,0) < 0) {
                        perror("msgsnd");
                }
                else    {
                printf("msg sending successful\n");
                printf("%ld\t%d\n",(long)getpid(),sbuf.num);
            }
        pause();
 // paused so that now parent can send the messages before children receive it

            for(j=0;j<n;j++)    {

            if (msgrcv(id2, &rbuf, buf_length, j, 0) < 0) {
                perror("msgrcv");
                }
            else    {
                printf("msg receiving successful\n");
                printf("%ld\t%d\n",(long)getpid(),sbuf.num);
            } 
        }

    }

}

else if(pid>0)  {


while(1)    {
sleep(3);
//sleeping so that children can first send the message
            if (msgrcv(id1, &rbuf, buf_length,0, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0) {
                perror("msgrcv");
                }
            else    {
                printf("msg receiving successful\n");

            sbuf.num=rbuf.num;
            sbuf.mtype=rbuf.mtype;
for(k=0;k<n;k++)    {
            if (msgsnd(id2, &sbuf, buf_length, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0) {
                perror("msgsnd parent\n");
                //exit(1);

            }
        }
    }
    }

}
}
}
```

Output:

```
Queue 1 created
Queue 2 created
msgsnd: Invalid argument
2 seconds elapsed
msgrcv: No message of desired type
msgrcv: No message of desired type
4 seconds elapsed
msgrcv: Interrupted system call
msgrcv: No message of desired type
6 seconds elapsed
msgrcv: Interrupted system call
msgrcv: No message of desired type
msgrcv: No message of desired type
8 seconds elapsed
msgrcv: Interrupted system call

(used ctrl+c here).
```

Comment: You compile this on which platform using which C implementation, please?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but there is no need to do `srand(time(...))` repeatedly. Just doing it once at the start of your program suffices.

Comment: @WhiteViking thnx for pointing out.

Comment: @alk I am using ubuntu 14.04 and and C version is gcc 4.9.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [msgsnd man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html):

> ...  The mtype field must have a *strictly positive* integer value. ...
>
> ...
>
> **EINVAL**
>
> Invalid msqid value, or *nonpositive mtype value*, or invalid msgsz
> value (less than 0 or greater than the system value MSGMAX).

You can't send a message with `mtype` set to zero.